# PHP - list all form elements within a div

Tags: php, forms, function

Is there a built in php function that will return an array (or some sort of list) of all the form elements within a div or within a specific form by either name or id?

My limited experience in javascript tells me that this can probably be occomplished with javascript but i am wondering if it can be done in php.  Thanks for your help.

My only other alternative would be to define a variable at the bottom of each form element like:

```
$allElements = 'name';
$allElements .= ', phone';
$allElements .= ', email'; 
and so on.
```

I am wondering if there is a short cut to this method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to parse the HTML.

```
$HTML = '<div name="phone"></div>';
$string = strstr($HTML, 'name=\"');
$string = strstr($string, '\"');
```

something like that...

these are your best friends:

```
stripos() 
strrpos() 
strripos() 
strstr() 
strpbrk()
substr()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know what you exactly mean.
All variables from a sent form are stored in the $_POST global variable. This will show you the list:

```
if ($_POST) {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo print_r($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Maybe you need to parse HTML with PHP - see the answer above.

Comment: Yeah think im looking for parse.  Thanks.